# Annoying lines between cubes while the Camera is moving in Unity3D

Tags: unity-game-engine

I made lot of cubes in a mesh with vertices. When I tested with color textures I could clearly see the lot of annoying gaps and lines popping up while the Camera is moving.

The mesh looks like this:

[image]

This is what it looks like when the camera is moving:

[image]

As the gif shows, there are lines popping up, how can I fix this?

Comment: maybe [this](https://answers.unity.com/questions/466353/shading-problems-with-cubes-next-to-each-other.html) will help. You might have better luck asking on https://gamedev.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like ["z-fighting"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Z-fighting). When two or more meshes overlap, placed very close together, rounding errors will cause them to fight when rendered. Possible solutions:

1. Create one cube and give it a [material/texture](https://answers.unity.com/questions/1229531/how-to-add-a-different-texture-to-each-face-of-a-c.html) with the desired colors.
2. Create three cubes on top of each other (do not let one, like the black one in your example, be bigger so it is overlapped by the red one).
3. If you really want to overlap the cubes, make them slightly different in size so the rounding errors will not show up.

Comment: Increasing the size of the cubes by 0.001f helped solve the problem. Thanks